# SQL query result with unique rows

Tags: sql

This is my table code:

```
create table Names(id int, Fname varchar(40), Lname varchar(40));
insert into Names values(1, 'Zuma', 'Zytaveon');
insert into Names values(2, 'Sara', 'Luqman');
insert into Names values(3, 'Zuma', 'Zytaveon');
insert into Names values(4, 'Rafe', 'Raphael');
```

If i run the  query

```
SELECT DISTINCT from Names 
WHERE Fname = 'Zuma' 
    AND Lname = 'Zytaveon';
```

i get the following out put.

```
1|Zuma|Zytaveon
3|Zuma|Zytaveon
```

I want to have Zuma Zytaveon only one time in my query results, So how can I get that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want the ID as well? Or just fname, lname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT FName, LName
from    Names 
WHERE   Fname = 'Zuma' AND Lname = 'Zytaveon';
```

if you want to have the lowest ID, use `MIN`

```
SELECT  MIN(ID) ID, FName, LName
from    Names 
WHERE   Fname = 'Zuma' AND Lname = 'Zytaveon'
GROUP   BY FName, LName
```

Comment: Although this is a correct statement, it seems rather useless to return only those columns where the values are known for sure (because of the  `where` clause). Could be that Vision is actually after something different...

Answer (score 0):

Various possibilities exist to select one element from a result set of multiple elements:

- Use the DISTINCT keyword to eliminate duplicates in the result set. This is done by first sorting, so takes O(N * Log N ) time (if no index available for the sort).
- Use an aggregate function such as MIN or MAX, requiring O(N) time to read the entire result set.
- Use the TOP 1 construct to return the first located row in O(1) time.

Choose one of these depending on the other business requirements of the problem.